# Chrome Extension not running scripts on document start and not printing content

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a small Chrome Extension, I wan't it to automatically redirect to "redirect.js" when you go to google.com.au, however it isn't working. If I manually go to the "blank.html" file which is shown in "redirect.js" it my "httpGet" function won't work.

#### manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Simon Extended",
  "description": "Beautify's Simon.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,

    "icons": {
    "512": "icon.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["redirect.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Simon Extended"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://google.com.au/*", "https://google.com.au/*"],
      "js": ["redirect.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### redirect.js:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlhttp.send();    
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    window.open("blank.html")
    document.write(httpGet("http://google.com"))
});
```

#### blank.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blank</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ehh sorry with the bad formatting... new to the whole stackoverflow thing.

Comment: There are many, many serious problems here, but the most important question is: _what are you trying to do_? I feel it's better to scrap this all than try to fix it, because you're approaching it wrong.

Comment: Another important thing is that **you cannot make XMLHttpRequests to google.com**, because the server rejects any request to that page. Xan is right. You shouldn't use a content script, take a look at the chrome.tabs API.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: One can use cross domain XHR in extensions. But one have to add correct permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: @user13500 nope, you can't make XHRs to google.com. It is true that you can make cross origin requests setting the content security policy field in your extension, and also using https, but you **cannot** make requests to Google's home page. Google's servers automatically reject any of these requests.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Not if you add `/ncr` as explicitly explained in answer. Without it the XHR fails, *but only if you have not added permissions for the country domain you are redirected to.*

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: It is not like .com fails even if you add .com to manifest persmissions, but e.g. .de, .co.uk, .se or .dk or what ever country site your request is forwarded to. Again: you have to set correct permissions in manifest.

Comment: @user13500 You don't seem to understand. Even if Chrome is programmed to ignore any kind of cross-domain restriction, Google's _servers_ will still not service the request the way you expect, because of layers upon layers of protection against scraping.

Comment: @Xan: Then try. Try to do a XHR request to `https://www.google.com/ncr` and see for yourself. Note that you need to add both `http://www.google.com` and `https://www.google.com` to permissions. I am not talking about doing search. But that is the same. A *"normal"* search request redirects to ccTLD. E.g. `https://www.google.com/search?q=xhr+is+working&output=search` is going to do a ccTLD request *unless* you first do a request to `/ncr`.

Comment: @Xan I'm a bit confused now, because I tried to access `https://www.google.com` before in the background of a test extension, setting both permissions and content security policy for the request, but it didn't go well. Now I've tried running the XHR again on an extension of mine and it suddenly works, even without the CSP field set in the manifest. So there are two options: 1) I foolishly didn't notice this before (I don't see how); 2) Google changed it's security measures; 3) What the heck idk

Comment: You can use [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) and [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) to redirect before going to a particular site.  But redirecting to "redirect.js" doesn't make sense.  Do you mean that whenever someone tries to go to google.com.au, it instead goes to google.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you say `window.open("blank.html");` you open a new tab where the URL is *your* extension.
2. When you want to `write` to that window you have to say something like:

   ```
   var win = window.open("blank.html");
   win.document.write('some HTML');
   ```
3. As google.***com*** uses redirect to local domain you have to add `ncr` to the path:
       https://www.google.com/ncr
4. As the XHR request is cross-domain you have to add permissions in your `manifest.json` file for target domain. Something like:

   ```
   "permissions": [
       "http://www.google.com/*",
       "https://www.google.com/*",
   ]
   ```
5. As this is an extension for Chrome, you know it has `XMLHttpRequest`, so no check needed. Further you can use `onload` instead of `onreadystatechange` with checks.
6. As WHATWG and Chrome hates anything synchronous you have to [use async request](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method):

   ```
   open("GET", url, true);
   ```
7. Now your issue becomes that you do not actually do a redirect, but rather fetches the code at *google.com* and writes it to your *local* html page for your extension. As such any relative paths to resources, (such as images, CSS, JavaScript files etc.), is not going to be accessible. If you want to go that direction you would have to add a `<base>`, (or parse and re-write all relative URLs).

Your final `redirect.js` could then be something like:

```
function http_set(url, win)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var html = xhr.responseText.replace('<head>', '<head><base href="'+url+'">');
        win.document.write(html);
        win.document.close();
    }
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var win = window.open("blank.html");
    http_set("https://www.google.com/ncr", win);
});
```

---

#### Go directly:

So, instead of *loading* the HTML code from google.com you could say something like:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    window.open("https://www.google.com/ncr");
});
```

Now. The effect of this would be that when you click the icon of your extension, a new tab is opened with google.com.

---

#### Really go directly:

For the effect you request you could instead have this `redirect.js` file:

```
window.location = "https://www.google.com/ncr";
```

yes, that is the entire file. With this you could then drop the permission thing we added in the manifest file, and only add trigger domains.

#### Match URL

And for that: you need to match `www` as well. E.g.:

```
  "matches": [
    "http://google.com.au/*",
    "https://google.com.au/*",
    "http://www.google.com.au/*",
    "https://www.google.com.au/*"
  ],
```

---

#### When all said and done:

OK. After all of this is said and done, it is likely not the best way to solve it. But I hope you at least have learned a thing or two.

The core of it is:

1. Practice and learn more JavaScript. As in the core of the language.
2. When writing extensions for a specific browser you are free to use the implementations it possess - without having to do cross-browser checks etc. Further you can take advantage of all the tools in that specific browsers bank.
3. When writing extensions you can utilize more of the back end power as the API gives. Many things are often done in a *bit different way* when it comes to extensions - as you have a wide range of extra tools to take advantage of.

Comment: Why down-vote? Is anything wrong then tell, so i can fix it or delete it.

Comment: Downvoted, because this answer is useless. It does not address important, extension-specific problems, most of it will not work because of that. It contains relevant points, but does not answer the question. Now, I argue that currently no answer can answer the question well, because the question itself is unclear and is an example of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) gone wrong, because OP has no idea how extensions work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'll be sure to fix my extension once I get home.